# Who are these ayah's (2:8-2:10) referring to?

Tags: quran, tafseer, prophet-muhammad, surat-al-baqarah, imaan

Al Salam Alaykum. I am a recent revert and my imaan has been increasing Alhamdulellah. I, however, have doubts every day or so about Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). I make dua for Allah to open my heart to Prophet Muhammad's excellence and Alhamdulellah that has been happening slowly. Yesterday in prayer, the imam read from Surah al Baqara and these ayahs caught my attention:

> وَمِنَ النَّاسِ مَن يَقُولُ آمَنَّا بِاللَّهِ وَبِالْيَوْمِ الْآخِرِ وَمَا هُم بِمُؤْمِنِينَ - 2:8
>
> يُخَادِعُونَ اللَّهَ وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَمَا يَخْدَعُونَ إِلَّا أَنفُسَهُمْ وَمَا يَشْعُرُونَ - 2:9
>
> فِي قُلُوبِهِم مَّرَضٌ فَزَادَهُمُ اللَّهُ مَرَضًا ۖ وَلَهُمْ عَذَابٌ أَلِيمٌ بِمَا كَانُوا يَكْذِبُونَ - 2:10

Translated into:

> 2:8 - And of the people are some who say, "We believe in Allah and the Last Day," but they are not believers.
>
> 2:9 - They [think to] deceive Allah and those who believe, but they deceive not except themselves and perceive [it] not.
>
> 2:10 - In their hearts is disease, so Allah has increased their disease; and for them is a painful punishment because they [habitually] used to lie.

Basically, I'm afraid if this is referring to me in my current state of imaan and hesitation towards Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As‘salaamu alaikum, brother.
The passage you cited is talking about “munaafiqun” = hypocrites, pretenders, imposters. People  who claimed to be muslims but, in truth, demonstrated no love, loyalty, or dedication to the Deen (nor to the  Umma) when it was time to struggle, suffer, or sacrifice. They used to be two-faced and fork-tongued with the prophet and the sincere Believers in an effort to stay in their good graces. You cited the passage as 2: 8 - 10, but the passage really goes to ayat 16. Read them and you will see that Allah is describing people who are in a BAD condition. He states plainly that they don‘t have  faith AT ALL (ayat 8), they lie a lot TRYING TO PULL THE WOOL OVER THE SINCERE BELIEVERS‘S EYES (ayah 9 and 10), they make mischief (ayah 11 and 12), and they are disloyal both to the Islamic faith doctrine and the Community (ayah 13 and 14).

Does that describe you akhi? I hope not! I think that what you lack is sufficient knowledge about Rasulullah (alaihi salaam). Study more about him, his works, and his life and you will soon come to love him. I leave you with this tidbit that I read in Martin Lings‘s book on the life of the Prophet: All prophets are given a prayer that will definitely be granted. Towards the end of  the Prophet‘s (a.s.) life the angel Jibreel came and asked him what his prayer was.

Muhammad (a.s.) said, “I‘m saving my prayer to pray for my Ummah on the Day of Judgment.”

Alhamdulillah! That‘s  love!! How can we not love him back? Ma‘as‘salaam bro. May Allah  make knowledge sweet to you. Amin.

Comment: Alaykum Al Salam brother. I have no words for how much I like your answer. JAK ya Ibraheem. Alhamdulellah, I am not one of those people described in ayat 8-16. I shall do as you say Insha2Allah and study about Prophet Muhammed's PBUH life and works. Your tidbit is really heartwarming. May Allah make knowledge sweet to us all. Ameen.

Comment: Alhamdulillahi Rabbil Aalameen!

Comment: Formatting your posts makes them more readable!

Answer (score 1):

After mentioning the believers and describing them in the beginning of the surah, Allah went forth mentioning the disbelievers and describing them. And then came to the description of those in the middle: Those who say they believe while they actually only act like believers!

Imam ibn Kathir introduced these verses in his tafsir by saying:

> We mentioned that four Ayat in the beginning of Surat Al-Baqarah described the believers. The two last Ayat (2:6-7) describe the disbelievers. Afterwards, Allah begins to describe the hypocrites who show belief and hide disbelief. Since the matter of the hypocrites is vague and many people do not realize their true reality, Allah mentioned their description in detail. Each of the characteristics that Allah used to described them with is a type of hypocrisy itself. Allah revealed Surat Bara'ah (chapter 9) and Surat Al-Munafiqun (chapter 63) about the hypocrites. He also mentioned the hypocrites in Surat An-Nur (24) and other Surahs, so that their description would be known and their ways and errors could be avoided. Allah said,
>
> (8. And of mankind, there are some who say: "We believe in Allah and the Last Day'' while in fact they do not believe). (9. They try to deceive Allah and those who believe, while they only deceive themselves, and perceive (it) not!) (Source: [qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=441))

Then he moved on describing the hypocrites:

> Nifaq means to show conformity - or agreement - and to conceal evil. Nifaq has several types: Nifaq in the creed that causes its people to reside in Hell for eternity, and Nifaq in deed, which is one of the major sins, as we will explain soon, Allah willing. Ibn Jurayj said of the hypocrite that, "His actual deeds are different from what he publicizes, what he conceals is different from what he utters, his entrance and presence are not the same as his exit and absence.''  (Source [qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=440))

I strongly recommend you to check the following pages on qtafsir for further information and details on the verses. Even if I must warn you that they may deviuate a bit by quoting the cirucmstances and history of the revelation of these verses too.

The last verse of your quote ([2:10](https://legacy.quran.com/2/10)):

> In their hearts is disease, so Allah has increased their disease; and for them is a painful punishment because they [habitually] used to lie.

actually has counter part or reference in the Qur'an:

> And whenever a surah is revealed, there are among the hypocrites those who say, "Which of you has this increased faith?" As for those who believed, it has increased them in faith, while they are rejoicing. (124)
>   But as for those in whose hearts is disease, it has [only] increased them in evil [in addition] to their evil. And they will have died while they are disbelievers. ([9:124-125](https://legacy.quran.com/9/124-125))

Most scholars say Imaan: Is saying and doing. This means believing by heart and expression and applying. As kufr in Arabic also means rejection while imaan means approval.

In your current state you need to learn about Islam and it is ok to have questions and doubts and its highly recommended to clear these doubts as "Allah loves/prefers to be worshiped by knowledge" as many scholars say, this means you must know and try to seek proofs to create a strong knowledge base against possibly upcoming doubts. As as long as you just blindly follow it is certain that your doubts may grow, while when you know why you do it, you get certainty. Therefore Allah points at this in the Qur'an saying:

- > And most of them follow not except assumption. Indeed, assumption avails not against the truth at all. Indeed, Allah is Knowing of what they do. ([10:36](https://legacy.quran.com/10/36))
- > And they have thereof no knowledge. They follow not except assumption, and indeed, assumption avails not against the truth at all. ([53:28](https://legacy.quran.com/53/28))

So if you have any doubt feel free to clear it by formulating it as questions and ask Muslims of your trust, scholars and ask for evidences as they might help you understand and accept and strengthen your imaan.

Comment: Jazak Allah Khayran @Medi1Saif for the incredible answer as always! There are so many great details in your answer and a lot of them really assuring as well as helpful. It's honestly wonderful to have you being as active as you are here on StackExchange. May Allah grant you, me and all of the Ummah Jannat Al Fardaws. Ameen.

Comment: @ Khalled O Allah 'Do not take me to task for what they say and forgive me for what they do not know.' [Al-Adab al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/adab/33/8)

Comment: I really like the sentiment of this hadith in your comment. Does it only apply to being praised for Islamic knowledge or any praise? Also what does "do not take me to task for what they say" mean?

Comment: @Khaled I have actually not looked for the detailed interpretation of this hadith. In fact there are two narrations of it I know of this one in al-Adab al-Mufrad and one which was quoted by imam al-Bayhaqi and which si a bit longer, I guess the last one is quoted in a booklet called Hisna al-Muslim which includes supplications and du'as for every matter. I guess it refers on what others may say about you, maybe praising maybe other things, but that's only my interpretation.

Comment: I also came across the longer narration which I also really like. I want to get to the bottom of this hadith because I have a habit of unintentionally enjoying any praise I get and I don't want to risk building any pride from it.